# mysql get friends from single table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a single table for friend request with status as pending , accepted or rejected, how to get my friends from this table ?
[image]

I followed this one but it is returning my own id i.e. 43

```
select distinct 
       case requester_user_id 
            when @myid then requested_user_id 
            else requester_user_id 
       end id
from friends
where @myid in (requester_user_id, requested_user_id)
```

I want to get user id 42 and 41 , please help!!! Thanks much.

Comment: Nice screenshot, but where's your code that you've tried already?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Where are you stuck?  There are many tutorials available for building SQL queries.

Comment: The simple `MYSQL query would be SELECT (requestFromUserId, RequestTouserId, status, created_at, updated_at) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE requestFromUserId = 42 OR reqestFromUserId = 41`

but without knowing where you want the data I have no idea how to help you more. Are you using PDO or MYSQLI or what..?

Comment: Are you sure you want 42 and 41? If so what rules are you using to expect those numbers

Comment: Thanks all for your response , please check my updated question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I want to get 41 and 42 since i am logged in as 43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IF condition in select statement to find friend_user_id.

```
select 
IF(@myid = requestFromUserId,requestToUserId,requestFromUserId) as friend_user_id 
from friends 
where (requestFromUserId = @myid or requestToUserId = @myid) and status = 'accepted'
```

Comment: it is returning my own id 43 twice

Comment: Ohh Yeah.. It was my mistake.. Please check the updated answer. If condition should be IF(@myid = requestFromUserId,requestToUserId,requestFromUserId) instead of IF(@myid = requestFromUserId,requestFromUserId,requestToUserId)

Comment: Thanks dude!!! its working fine.

Comment: You are welcome dude..